# How to use "Local Service" instead of "Local System"?

Tags: c#, windows-services

I install my C# service (currently on Windows 7 ; I've read it exists only *since* XP and 2003, but it should be all I need to handle) using the ServiceProcessInstaller. My service can run under "Local System" but not "Local Service" nor "Network Service". Even if my service is basically empty (see code below), I still get

> Windows could not start the [service name] service on Local Computer.
>   Error 5: Access is denied.

Here is my mostly empty service:
EDIT I updated the code to give "Local Service" the necessary access rights.

```
// Needs System.Configuration.Install.dll and System.ServiceProcess.dll
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Configuration.Install;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.ServiceProcess;

namespace ServiceTest
{
    static class Constants
    {
    public const string LocalServiceAcctName = @"NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE";
        public const string ServiceName = "MySvc";
    }

    class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Main entry point.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="args">
        ///     If the 1st argument is "i", it will simply install the service.
        ///     If it's something else, it will run as a Console application.
        ///     If it's empty, it will run as a service.
        /// </param>
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args != null && args.Length != 0 && args[0] == "i")
            {
                bool result = InstallService(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location, Constants.ServiceName);
                Console.WriteLine(result ? "INSTALLED" : "ERROR INSTALLING");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else
            {
                var host = new Host();
                bool runAsSvc = args == null || args.Length == 0;
                host.Launch(runAsSvc);
            }
        }

        static bool InstallService(string exeFullPath, string serviceName)
        {
            AssemblyInstaller installer = new AssemblyInstaller(exeFullPath, null);

            if (ServiceController.GetServices().Any(svcCtlr => svcCtlr.ServiceName == serviceName))
                installer.Uninstall(null);

            Hashtable dico = new Hashtable();
            installer.Install(dico);
            installer.Commit(dico);

        // Gives "Local Service" the necessary rights on the folder and subfolders and files.
        DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Path.GetDirectoryName(exeFullPath));
        DirectorySecurity dirSec = dirInfo.GetAccessControl(AccessControlSections.Access);

        FileSystemRights rights = FileSystemRights.Modify;
        AccessControlType accessType = AccessControlType.Allow;
        dirSec.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(Constants.LocalServiceAcctName, rights, InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.InheritOnly, accessType));
        dirSec.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(Constants.LocalServiceAcctName, rights, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit, PropagationFlags.InheritOnly, accessType));
        dirSec.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(Constants.LocalServiceAcctName, rights, accessType));
        dirInfo.SetAccessControl(dirSec);


            return true;
        }
    }

    class Host
    {
        internal void Launch(bool runAsSvc)
        {
            if (runAsSvc)
                RuntimeService.CreateAndRun(this);
            else
            {
                OnStart();
                Console.WriteLine("Component started as a Console app.");
                Console.WriteLine("We work a lot...and then we're done.");
                OnStop();

                Console.WriteLine("Press enter to stop.");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        internal void OnStart() { Console.WriteLine("We're starting!"); }

        internal void OnStop() { Console.WriteLine("We're stopping..."); }
    }

    class RuntimeService : ServiceBase
    {
        Host _host;

        public RuntimeService(Host host) { _host = host; }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args) { _host.OnStart(); }

        protected override void OnStop() { _host.OnStop(); }

        internal static void CreateAndRun(Host host) { ServiceBase.Run(new RuntimeService(host)); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Class used to install the service.
    /// </summary>
    [RunInstaller(true)]
    public class RuntimeInstaller : Installer
    {
        public RuntimeInstaller()
        {
            var processInstaller = new ServiceProcessInstaller();
            processInstaller.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalService; // ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;

            var serviceInstaller = new ServiceInstaller();
            serviceInstaller.StartType = ServiceStartMode.Automatic;
            serviceInstaller.ServiceName = Constants.ServiceName;

            Installers.Add(serviceInstaller);
            Installers.Add(processInstaller);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where have you installed the service? The error seems to indicate that the Local Service account does not have access to the service location. So the service manager cannot even load the executable and get it running let alone start the service.

I've frequently seen developers do this when developing/debugging a service. They install the service from one of their development folders but set it to run under another account. But by default only the user, the system and the administrators group have access to a user's folders - so the service fails with an access denied error.

Comment: You are so right. The folder was on my desktop and "Local Service" didn't have any right on it. I just added "Read & execute", "List folder contents" and "Read" and now it starts fine. Thanks a lot, I really didn't think of that!

Answer (score 0):

What Operating system are you using?

According to [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.serviceaccount%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> The values LocalService and NetworkService are available only on Windows XP and Windows Server 2003 family.

When I first read this comment [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.serviceaccount%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), I assumed it was written when these operating systems were the latest version and was there to exclude earlier operating systems, but this comment still exists in the latest documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the quote. I'm on Win7 with .Net 4, but it still looks like LocalService and NetworkService are available: it compiles and I can install the service using both (I see "Log on as" is set to "Local Service" or "Network Service" in services.msc - also there are lots of Windows services using those accounts). Maybe they forgot to update their doc, as those accounts are only available *starting* with XP and 2003?

Comment: Proof it works with Windows 8 : http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=EwTYYPRcWj0#t=363s

Comment: Apparently it depends on the privileges your service needs. My service with WCF included will not run on Win 7. Please refer to:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684190%28v=vs.85%29.aspx, this does support that the Microsoft statement is incorrect though.